# PHP - class intern static registry array(&$this) not working

Tags: php, reference, this, static-array

Greetings dear Community,
I am trying to write a class which keeps track of all instances internally via a static array of references to each object:

```
# MyObject.php
class MyObject{
  public static $_register = array();
  public        $_id    = -1;
  public        $_value = '';

  function __construct( $value ){
    $this->_value = $value;
    $this->_id    = count( self::$_register );

    self::$_register[ $this->_id ] =& $this;  // I also tried '= &$this'
  }

  function foo(){                                  // outputs 'id : value'
    echo $this->_id.' : ' . $this->_value . '<br />';
  }
}
```

But when I try to alter `$_register` in my main script:

```
#main.php
require_once( 'MyObject.php' );

$test = new MyObject( 'hihi' );
$test->foo();                                     // outputs '0 : hihi'

MyObject::$_register[0] = NULL;

$test->foo();                                     // still outputs '0 : hihi'
```

It still outputs '0 : hihi'. A `var_dump( MyObject::$_register[0] )` showed that it's set to NULL, but the should-be-referenced MyObject still points to the same Instance.

I am trying to understand references in PHP and this behaviour was unexpected for me. Could someone please explain it.

Thanks in advice

P.S: Before I tried a little C++/Qt and the difference in usage of references/pointers is making me dizzy.

Comment: PHP counts references: `unset`-ting them needs to be done on _all_ references before it disappears. You may have removed the object from the `_register`, but you did not destroy it: it is _still_ inline accessible as `$test`, and so can easily `echo $this->_id.' : ' . $this->_value;`. The reverse is also true: `unset($test);` would still have the object available in `self::$_register`.

Comment: In PHP "most" instantiated objects are always passed by reference. There is no need to use a pointer. You can simply assign `$this` and have reference to it. [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

Answer (score 1):

That's because with unset you'll destroy only *reference* to object, but not object itself. This may seems odd, but unsetting a reference is treated as destroying reference, not entity to which that reference is pointing.

In PHP, however, **reference** is NOT a **pointer**. The big difference is shown in PHP [references tutorial](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/references-tutorial/). So in common case - no, you can not unset an entity with given reference to it. Remember: PHP references have nothing to do with C-pointers.

Comment: Ok then why `$bar =& $test; $bar = NULL;` behaves another way. When I try to evaluate `$test->foo();` afterwards it's erroring. As for explicit use of '=&': somewhere in the 'Passing by reference' manual I read that references to objects are not always the same. That's why I use '=&' to be sure to be experimenting with references.

Comment: Because assign some value isn't same operation as unsetting variable